# How to get a substring from starting character to end character in unix korn shell

Tags: shell, datetime, unix, substring

I'm trying to see if there's an easier way to get a substring from starting character to an end character to identify "date format" that it has, I have a solution that is working but I'm looking if there's a way much easier to do it.

```
EXAMPLE:
file_name=file_test_<yyyymmdd>_format.xls

SUBSTRING FROM "<" to ">"
<yyyymmdd>
```

this is what I have and is working:

```
file_name="test_file_<mmddyyyy>_test"
format_date=""
Char_Found=0
index=0
while [ $index -lt ${#file_name} ]; do
   letter=$(echo $file_name | cut -c$(( $index + 1 )))
   if [ $letter == "<" ]; then
     Char_Found=1
   fi

   if [ $letter == ">" ]; then
      format_date=${format_date}">"
      break
   fi

   if (( ${Char_Found} )); then
      format_date=${format_date}"${letter}"
   fi

   index=$(( $index + 1 ))
done

echo "Format string: ${format_date}"

#OUTPUT: <mmddyyyy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted implementation is not only lengthy,
it's very inefficient, due to calling `cut` in a loop,
for every character.

A simpler, far more efficient solution is possible with what is called *parameter expansion* in Bash,
which seems to work just fine in ksh too:

```
file_name="test_file_<mmddyyyy>_test"
format_date=$file_name
format_date="<${format_date#*<}"    # chop off the beginning until <
format_date="${format_date%%>*}>"   # chop off the end from >
echo "Format string: ${format_date}"
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Format string: <mmddyyyy>
> ```

Comment: Nice, it is working and it's helping me to write few more lines of code!
Thanks.